# minted escapeinside works for all supported languages except LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, minted, latex3, highlighting, syntax-highlighting

I want to add some math symbols into the escaped contents, `minted` works well for languages like Python, but not LaTeX. A sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{latex}
|$\theta$|
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
|$\theta$|
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: escapeinside doesn't work for latex]

Any hint?

Comment: Neither `mathescape` works.

Answer (score 1):

An awkward workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mytheta}{$\theta^2$}
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{latex}
|this is \mytheta.|
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
|$\theta$|
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Still trying to find a better method...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the issue is switching to math mode.

A less ugly workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\mmath}[1]{$#1$}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{latex}
|\mmath{\theta}|
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
|$\theta$|
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]